# Hypothesis Testing Question: 1 Sided

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A teacher at a school claims that the students in her class are above average intelligence. A random sample of 30 students IQ scores have a mean score of 112. Is there sufficient evidence to support the teacher's claim? The mean population IQ is 100 with a standard deviation of 15.

The alpha level = 0.05

The critical value = 1.645

I don't know what formula to use to find the test statistics.

Comment: you use the z-test because the s.d. is known

Comment: How do you know that it's known?

Comment: I get confused when to use the z and t test

Comment: well you use z when the s.d. is known and t when it's unknown. It will be stated

Comment: Okay, thanks! @AmR

Comment: The t-test formula is the same, right?

Comment: not exactly the same, but similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) State the null and alternate hypothesis:

$H_0:μ = 100$
$H_1:μ > 100$

2) Find the alpha level. There was no alpha level given so by default we use $0.05$.

3) Find the reject region (critical value). By using the z-table, the area of $0.05$ is equal to the z-score of $1.645$.

4) Find the test statistic.

$Z=\frac{\bar{x}-μ}{σ/\sqrt{n}}$

= $\frac{112.5-100}{15/\sqrt{30}}$

= 4.56

5) Since the test statistics of 4.56 is greater than the critical value of 1.645, we reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: How does a random sample of 30 students infer that the students in her class have above average IQs? I know its only academic but to me it's not a very well thought out question.

Comment: Yeah i really didn't like the way it was worded.

Comment: I up voted your answer for the math procedure and for the fact that you steered clear of making a summary conclusion.

Comment: My teacher uses this example for all the classes she teaches

Comment: My older brother had her 4 years ago and he remembers having that question

Answer (score 2):

Since the standard deviation of 15 is known, you would use the formula: $Z=\frac{\bar{x}-μ}{σ/\sqrt{n}}$. Where $\bar{x}$ = 112, $μ = 100$, $σ = 15$, and $n = 30$.

If the test statistic is less than the critical value, you fail to reject the null.
If test statistic is greater than the critical value, you reject the null.